# Canonical issues- incorrect URL shown on home page

Tags: joomla-3.4, sef

I'm having canonical issues with my website. When I visit the homepage, I see `http//www.vincousa.com/?productsublayout=0` as the URL in my address bar. I would like `http://www.vincousa.com` as the URL.

I'm using VirtueMart 3.0.9 with Joomla version 3.4.3.

Comment: Please update to Joomla 3.4.5 immediately. By providing your URL, your site is prone to being hacked within 10 minutes.

Comment: What SEF components are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your templates index.php file before the closing body tag:

```
$JInput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$itemid = $JInput->get('Itemid','','int');
if($itemid == 'YOUR NUMERIC HOME PAGE ITEMID'){
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    $doc->addHeadLink(JUri::root(),'canonical');
}
```

that will reset your canonical link on your homepage to be the URL of you site.

Answer (score -1):

Just clear your browser cache, no need to edit your PHP files.
And conical is best set in .htaccess file you know how that works yes?